# Glossaries \printglossary suddenly not working (0 entries accepted, 3 rejected)

Tags: glossaries, linguistics, leipzig

I'm trying to use the `glossaries` package to make a list of abbreviations used in glossed linguistics examples (for which I use the package `gb4e`).  Basically, the problem I'm getting is that my glossary will print for awhile, but eventually it will stop printing, usually after I add a `\newglossaryentry` and reference it in the document, or after I shift the structure of the document around a bit (e.g. moving sections around).  Any idea what the issue could be?

Here is the error I get upon executing the `glossary_run` engine in TexShop (note `0 entries accepted, 3 rejected` after scanning `/Thesis.glo`):

```
Input index file ./Thesis.acn not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2016] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./Thesis.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file ./Thesis.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 3 rejected).
Nothing written in ./Thesis.gls.
Transcript written in ./Thesis.glg.
```

Whenever it works, I will get `(3 entries accepted, 0 rejected)` rather than `(0 entries accepted, 3 rejected)`, but I can't figure out why they suddenly become rejected.  Interestingly, once the entries start to be rejected, they will continue to be rejected even if I undo whatever appeared to be the offending move (i.e. they are still rejected even after I remove the last reference or shift the structure of the document back to how it was before).

I've been playing around with it for the past few days, and I noticed that the last time it stopped working was after I added a `\newglossaryentry` and referenced it within a `gb4e` example in a section that was added to the main document via the command `\include`.

A few more things which may be of importance:

1. I am always using small caps for the name of my glossary entries; for instance:

`\newglossaryentry{obl}{name=\textsc{obl}, description={oblique case}}`

2. I only use the command `\gls{}` to reference glossary entries, and the name always appears as it should in the text after compiling (the issue is only with printing the glossary).
3. I started out by using the `leipzig` package, which was created expressly for the purpose of managing a list of glossing abbreviations.  When I couldn't get this work, I switched to the `glossaries` package.  I understand that `leipzig` automatically loads `glossaries` upon being called, so I am thinking that the problem can be reduced to something in my use of `glossaries`.
4. A MWE which shows the structure of my master file and my glossary entries (note that I've pasted the content of the Introduction here, where it would normally be a file added via `\include`; note also that this MWE compiles with the glossary printed for me, but the glossary is not printed when I include the remaining sections):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[X2,LFE, LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,arabic,english]{babel}



%%% Packages & Page Settings %%%
%\input{PackagesAndPageSettings}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%% Commands %%%
%\input{Macros}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%Glossary%%%
    
 \usepackage[block, nopostdot, smallcaps, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
}

\newglossaryentry{selfobl}{name=\textsc{self.obl}, description={oblique reflexive pronoun}}
\newglossaryentry{selfemph}{name=\textsc{self.emph}, description={emphatic anaphor}}
\newglossaryentry{obl}{name=\textsc{obl}, description={oblique case}}


\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.8\hsize}

    \makeglossaries



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%\include{Content/frontmatter}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Research background and impetus}

I want to talk about the \gls{obl} case and how it is related to the \gls{selfemph} and \gls{selfobl} anaphors.

\printglossary[style=mystyle, title=Glossing abbreviations]

%\include{Content/phonology}

%...

%\include{Content/references}

\end{document}
```

Finally, I'm wondering if the problem could have anything to do with:

(i) the other packages I'm using or the order in which they are loaded (though note that I always have `hyperref` before `glossaries`)

(ii) the `glossaries_run` engine which I made executable the other day

(iii) my version of Perl (v5.18.4)

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: a minimal example that doesn't demonstrates the issue is rather useless. Apart from this: be warned, arabtex is *very* old and unmaintained. I just saw that it patches \document and \enddocument, and this means that there is a real danger that something will break with the next latex version. If you need arabic, why don't you use a modern engine like xelatex or lualatex which correctly support this script?

Comment: Thanks for having a look @UlrikeFischer.  I've taken your advice and am switching to xelatex, which has already simplified things quite a bit.  However, I'm now encountering a problem where tables are not compiling when I use the polyglossia package with Arabic set as one of the other languages.  I've asked a question with a MWE (which actually does display the errors this time) here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561951/xelatex-tables-not-compiling-when-using-polyglossia-arabic